# Changing value in inputs angularjs/html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with ng-repeat function from angularjs in html. My input with id 'add-price' in every single cartproduct change the same way, for example when I increase value in first cartproduct from 1 to 2 in second, third and other cartproducts value in input increase from 1 to 2 too.

Here is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cartproduct in store.cartproducts" bs-popover>
   <td>{{cartproduct.cartname}}</td>
   <td>{{cartproduct.cartbrutto}}</td>
   <td>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input id="add-price" class="form-control" type="number" min="1" step="any" name="counter" ng-model="product.counter" ng-change="store.calculateRow(cartproduct.cartbrutto)" placeholder="1">
       </div>
  </td>
  <td>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input id="add-final-price" class="form-control" type="text" name="row" ng-model="product.row" placeholder="{{cartproduct.cartbrutto}}">
       </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Help please!

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its updating same everywhere because, you are sharing same reference of `counter` on each `ng-model`

I'd say that make that `counter` value relative to `cartproduct` instead of having it in `product`

**Markup**

```
<input id="add-price" class="form-control" type="number" min="1" 
 step="any" name="counter" ng-model="cartproduct.counter" 
 ng-change="store.calculateRow(cartproduct.cartbrutto)" placeholder="1">
```

Comment: OMG, what a stupid error. I had product in other ng-repeat function and copy it here. I had not noticed that I didn't change name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @johnpol23 Glad to hear that it got work.. Thanks :-) don't forget to accept answer.. Thanks :-)